# Rxjava2 Compose then subscribe on another thread error

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a ObservableTransformer which has some computations in it. I want to use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)` then `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)` before subscription but error occurs(`IllegalStateException: Expected to be called on the main thread`) if I used it before subscribe operator. How can I make this subscribe on worker thread and observe on MainThread? this is how my code looks like:

```
Observable
   .compose(event())
   .subscribe()

ObservableTransformer<Event,Model> event(){

   return events -> events
            .publish(shared -> Observable.merge(
                    shared.ofType(EventModel.class)
                            .compose(action()),
                    shared.ofType(EventModel1.class)
                            .compose(action1()))
            .scan(initialState,(state,result) -> {

                //computation here


            });
}
```

EDIT:

I tried using this:

```
<T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {
    return observable -> observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

Observable
   .compose(event())
   .compose(applySchedulers())
   .subscribe()
```

Which I have found in a blog but still returns an illegalStateExecption

EDIT 2:

Here is the stacktrace:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to be called on the main thread but was RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
             at com.jakewharton.rxbinding2.internal.Preconditions.checkMainThread(Preconditions.java:35)
             at com.jakewharton.rxbinding2.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayoutRefreshObservable.subscribeActual(SwipeRefreshLayoutRefreshObservable.java:20)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual(ObservableObserveOn.java:45)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap.subscribeActual(ObservableMap.java:33)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableConcatMap$ConcatMapDelayErrorObserver.drain(ObservableConcatMap.java:469)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableConcatMap$ConcatMapDelayErrorObserver.onSubscribe(ObservableConcatMap.java:324)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray.subscribeActual(ObservableFromArray.java:30)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableConcatMap.subscribeActual(ObservableConcatMap.java:54)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner(ObservableFlatMap.java:162)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray$FromArrayDisposable.run(ObservableFromArray.java:107)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray.subscribeActual(ObservableFromArray.java:36)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap.subscribeActual(ObservableFlatMap.java:55)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner(ObservableFlatMap.java:162)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray$FromArrayDisposable.run(ObservableFromArray.java:107)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray.subscribeActual(ObservableFromArray.java:36)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap.subscribeActual(ObservableFlatMap.java:55)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservablePublishSelector.subscribeActual(ObservablePublishSelector.java:59)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableScanSeed.subscribeActual(ObservableScanSeed.java:47)
             at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
             at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
             at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:463)
             at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
             at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
             at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
             at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: What is the source? What is the stacktrace? Have you tried applying `subscribeOn(mainThread())` before the `compose(event())`?

Comment: @akarnokd I have edited my question. btw I tried using your suggestion and it worked. can you explain what happened here?

Comment: You had a `subscribeOn(io())` and Android complained about the wrong thread. Such errors usually happen when the source is a GUI component which are thread sensitive by default. From there, `subscribeOn(mainThread())` was a straightforward next step. Perhaps you should read a bit on RxJava Schedulers (Google it).